# Apache POI exits without throwing exception

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

First of all, the code below has worked without problems for a while now. 
I receive excel files from a colleague, which I read and upload with this program. 
Recently the colleague was replaced, and I receive the files from another person.
I'll check with him as well what exactly he does with the excel file.

Anyway, the first excel file I receive from the new colleague is getting me frustrated. 
The code below exits on the `WorkbookFactory.create(fis)` call. No exceptions are thrown 
and the program goes straight to the `finally` clause...

```
try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);            

        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

        Sheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        if (ws == null) {
            throw new ParseException("No sheet found on index 0", 1);
        }

        Iterator rowIt = ws.rowIterator();

        while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
            Row row = (Row) rowIt.next();
            if (row.getRowNum() != 0 && isArticleRow(row)) {
                Article article = parseArticleData(row);

                if (article != null) {
                    priceList.getArticles().add(article);
                }
            }
        }

        String vendorNumber = getVendorNumber(priceList);
        priceList.setVendorNumber(vendorNumber);

        priceList.setReadCorrectly(true);
        System.out.println("DONE");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        _log.error(e.getMessage());
        if (priceList != null) {
            priceList.setReadCorrectly(false);
        }

    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        return priceList;
    }
```

I tried debugging, but I experience the same behaviour, and without an 
exception being thrown, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: What does using the debugger show you is happening? ;)

Comment: Not a clean solution but try catching "Throwable" instead of exception and then print it out to see what the issue is... Most likely a runtime error is being thrown...

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this was actually all I needed. It seems some poi xml jars where missing. Since the previous colleague used a different excel format poi never needed the xml libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch Throwable and see instead of Exception. It should work.

```
} catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    _log.error(e.getMessage());
    if (priceList != null) {
        priceList.setReadCorrectly(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yep, it works, I caught the exception and caught a classDefNotFound error. See my comment above, some jars were missing.
Thanks a lot